# What type of data is causing the zero Sigma in Anfis?

Tags: neural-networks, matlab, fuzzy

I find this paragraph in "Intelligent Systems and Applications: Extended and Selected Results from the ..." book that discarded some data from dataset because they were not acceptable by the MATLAB ANFIS and sigma was zero.

[image: sigma is zero]

My question is which type of data is in this condition?

```
Illegal parameters in fisGaussianMF() --> sigma = 0
```

Does input data have a special relationship with the output to causing the zero Sigma in Anfis training?

I'm searched about this but I could not find any help.